# Arcgis Map Current Location

Tags: java, android, dictionary, arcgis

Hie, im new in using arcgis in Android to display map on Android phone.
I manage to display the map on the Android phone, however , i am having difficulties to show the current location. 
As in,at your current location, it would display a small blue dot.

Do you guys know how to show your current location using arcgis ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should perhaps consider using gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do it get the MapView's LocationService and call start() on it. But you need to do it after the map has been initialized. Here's a simple way to do that in your Activity's onCreate method (assuming your MapView is named map):

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
        if (STATUS.INITIALIZED == status) {
            map.getLocationService().start();
        }                
    }

});
//Then add layers to the map
```

Comment: I tried your codes under my onCreate .When i run the program, it does not locate me to my location

Comment: When I said "Then add layers to the map," I meant it. Call setOnStatusChangedListener **before** calling addLayer. Otherwise, your map will probably get initialized before setOnStatusChangedListener gets called, so that onStatusChanged never gets called, so you never start the LocationService. If you want to know for sure, run in debug mode or put a [log statement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) right before the call to map.getLocationService().start() .